# Good tools/frameworks to develop a game server in Java?

Tags: java, frameworks

I am making a game server for a turn based game. Not a web based server, but a process-based one. I want it to be scalable and I want the development process to go as smoothly as possible. I haven't used Java in forever and I need to brush up on my skills, so I really have no idea what is out there framework or tool-wise. Right now it looks like I am going to use [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/web/display/orgsite/Home) due to its clustering capabilities. I was just wondering if anything besides this that would make developing a TCP based game server easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Project Darkstar](http://www.projectdarkstar.com/).

Comment: Wikipedia: "February 2, 2010, Oracle shut down the project, and a community fork has been made called RedDwarf Server". http://www.reddwarfserver.org/

Comment: @JuliusEckert That site is down as well.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Marauroa. It is a client server framework for turn based games. There is even a MORPG based on it, with the turn time set down to only 300ms.

But it is not designed for cluster support.

http://arianne.sf.net/wiki/index.php/Marauroa

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [SmartFoxServer](http://www.smartfoxserver.com/)?  It's Java and already supports [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org).

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug: Here is a [java game server](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server) written by me. Has UDP and TCP support. jetserver also has a java client as well as flash action script client already developed. Clustering is not yet implemented.